# Replacing Variables in Limit Defintion

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I am reading an introductory book on complex analysis. They define the neighborhood of infinity as $|z| > 1/\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$. Then they wish to show the following statement:
$$ \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}f(z) = w_0 \quad \text{iff} \quad \lim_{z \rightarrow 0}=f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

Their proof goes as follows:

> In the forward direction, note by definition we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \, \exists \delta > 0$ st:
>   $$|z| > 1/\delta \implies |f(z) - w_0| < \epsilon$$
>   **Replacing $z$ by $1/z$** we obtain:
>   $$0 < |z - 0| > \delta \implies |f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) - w_0| < \epsilon$$

Why can they just "replace" $z$ with $1/z$? Can I do this with any function of $z$ like $z^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute anything you like but you must respect the inequalities.

In this case we have that $|z| > 1/\delta \implies |f(z) - w_0| < \epsilon$ and a straight replacement gives us $|\frac{1}{z}| > 1/\delta \implies |f(\frac{1}{z}) - w_0| < \epsilon$.

Taking reciprocals on the left side of the implication, we get $|z|\lt\delta\implies |f(\frac{1}{z})-w_0|\lt\epsilon$

Comment: 1. Should it be $|f(1/z)-w_0|$ (parenthesis at end is in the wrong place?)? 2. Can you elaborate "you can substitute anything you like so long as it respects the inequality" -- this is the crux of my confusion. Continuity is about "closeness in the range implies closeness in the domain" -- why can I just change variables in the statement?

Comment: Yes. That’s a typo. Variables are just place holders. Why wouldn’t we be able to change variables? When we substitute $z$ with $\frac{1}{z}$, we still require the fraction to have the same properties as the original variable.